# Invalid syntax in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a column,'mdiff', calculating the difference between the max and min values of the 'POP...' columns.
It gives me a syntax error on line where : res=df1.nlargest(1)  (I'm trying to fetch the largest value here). I'm not sure what can be wrong here?
The data is a dataframe with columns `CTYNAME, POPOPESTIMATE2010,..2011,..2012,..2013,..2014..2015.`

```
def maxdiff():
    rows =['POPESTIMATE2010',
    'POPESTIMATE2011',
    'POPESTIMATE2012',
    'POPESTIMATE2013',
    'POPESTIMATE2014',
    'POPESTIMATE2015']
    df1=df.where(df['SUMLEV']==50).set_index(['CTYNAME']).dropna()
    df1['mdiff']=df1.apply(lambda x: abs(np.max(x[rows]-np.(min(x[rows])), 
    axis=1)
    dmax=df1.nlargest(1,'mdiff')   

    return dmax
```

Comment: What about simply `df['mdiff] = df.max(1) - df.min(1)`?

Comment: thanks, @Josh Friedlander, your idea worked (see the code below). Do you know how to make it work with lambda?= how you'd change my original code?
rows = ['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']
    df1=df.where(df['SUMLEV']==50).set_index(['CTYNAME']).dropna()
    df1['maxdiff']=abs(df1.max(axis=1) - df1.min(axis=1))
    res=df1.filter(['CTYNAME','maxdiff'], axis=1).nlargest(3,'maxdiff')
    return res.index[0]
print(maxdiff())

Comment: Glad it worked. Do you mind saying why you want to use a lambda? It's slower so better to avoid it unless there's a good reason

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in the lambda expression:

```
def maxdiff():
    rows = [
        "POPESTIMATE2010",
        "POPESTIMATE2011",
        "POPESTIMATE2012",
        "POPESTIMATE2013",
        "POPESTIMATE2014",
        "POPESTIMATE2015",
    ]
    df1 = (
        df.where(df["SUMLEV"] == 50)
        .set_index(["CTYNAME"])
        .dropna()
    )
    df1["mdiff"] = df1.apply(
        lambda x: abs(np.max(x[rows] - np.min[rows])),  # <-- One more `)` here!
        axis=1
    )
    dmax = df1.nlargest(1, "mdiff")

    return dmax
```

Comment: yes, thats it!   the next problem I face is  that dmax is not defined... you answered my question though